# Firebase messenger sends a notification but iOS device doesn't receive anything

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get a notification to send from firebase cloud messenger to single device. I've installed firebase and when I run the program the console prints out the fcm token which I attempt to use to send a message to that device (I'm using a real iPhone). The message sends fine but nothing ever appears on my iPhone. I implemented the code below in the App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)



    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert])          { (granted, error) in
            if granted
            {
                //self.registerCategory()
            }
        }
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    }
    else
    {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =  UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert,.badge,.sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    //Configuring Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)


    return true
}


//Receive Remote Notification on Background
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

}

@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm()
{
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
{
    connectToFcm()
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

[This is the response I get from the Firebase end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1WJa.png)

So it says no messages were sent, which I'm confused about because it is the token my device has just outputted as having.

How can I find out more about or solve this problem?

Comment: Have you uploaded the auth keys for sending notifications?
Please follow the below link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Comment: 1. Double check the info in the page @vishalwaka posted (ie. Bundle ID, etc.)
2. If you're using certificates (instead of keys), make sure you're using development keys and not production

Comment: Did you set the property `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` in your apps `info.plist` file. If you did what value did you give it?

Comment: @Barns I have FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled set to NO in Info.plist

Comment: @PeterTao I'm using APN key or .p8 file

Answer (score 0):

before run messege from fcm console check .p12 file is uploaded

[image]

then implement the message handling methods 
in foreground and background

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    }

    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

   }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }


    completionHandler()

}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
print("Firebase registration token: (fcmToken)")
}
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
print("Received data message: (remoteMessage.appData)")
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't have the APN file uploaded but now I do , I also implemented your code and there is still no change. It sends but is not received.

Comment: I was using a .p8 file instead as I've heard they are good but I've now decided to try a .p12 file to see if that was the problem. I've gotten an issue with the bundleID , maybe you will see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537059/firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-the-certificates-bundleid-did-not-match-tha

Comment: what you upload file does not match with your buble id

Comment: fallow the link generate .p12 file https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/